# How do I get show-doc to work with pry for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pry

I installed pry and pry-doc on Ubunutu WSL for Windows 10. When I try to use show-doc on pry to get information about a method it doesn't work.
[Picture of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfkmP.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'pry-doc'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> show-doc String#end_with?
Error: Cannot locate this method: end_with?. (source_location returns nil)
```

Comment: What ruby version?

Comment: ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Confirm you are using pry-doc 1.3.0 which appears to have added support for 3.1: https://github.com/pry/pry-doc/commit/96cfed5dc80c2e9cac9731605c11b67c8dfd4d75

Comment: Yes I'm using pry-doc 1.3.0.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue you are experiencing. I would open an issue with `pry-doc`  https://github.com/pry/pry-doc/issues

Comment: I will do that. Thanks so much for the help.